# Nuxt(vue) understanding fetch and lighthouse score

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm trying to decrease my lighthouse score, now 20-50.
I added nuxt-ssr-cache and nuxt-delay-hydration.

First I would like to hear about ways to improve the score.
My question is about how fetch works with children components, lest say I have

parent -> child1 -> child2

Each one of theme has fetch request and each child depends on his parent request, so child2 needs to wait child1 finish fetch and child1 need to wait parent.
Now the time the server takes to render is sum of all fetch components right?
So the best answer will be to provide all data with one request for all 3 components that will decrease request time, but what the point on using fetch and no asyncData with this approach.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This question is difficult to answer because performance is a large topic and a lot of things can slow down your app. On top of it, it's too broad for a SO question.

I do have a more detailed opinion that you can read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67319935/8816585

---

You can also follow this guy, he is heavily focused into e-commerce + Nuxt and how to get the most performance out of it: https://twitter.com/filrakowski
He did a nice talk during [Nuxtnation](https://nuxtnation.com/), the video should be up in some time IMO: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7H2HJUUqvdArYMBsrDmecw/videos

Comment: Lcp isn't my main problem, Time to interactive is the main problem and I didn't found info about it, also I didn't get answer about the effectively of fetch vs async data with multiply request.

Comment: @nadav using `fetch` or `asyncData` is not really related to webperf but more of a way of displaying things tbh. And my answer above was about generic web perf, so even if LCP is not the main focus, everything else is still relevant.